# I need to make a clean, nice-looking map for a presentation based on a Google map. Any easy way to do this?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, arcgis

I want to make a very clean map that *only* shows relevant information - e.g., only the streets that matter. I was going to just draw a map while looking at Google's, but that turned out to be very slow. Is there any way to make this easier, perhaps with some combination of mapping software and Google's API?

(If I should of put this on another SE site, please tell me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you mean you want to only show "streets that matter", you are out of luck with using Google Maps. Because you have no control over the ROADMAP data that google provides. Now what you can do, is use another mapping software such as ArcGIS or Quantum GIS (which is free). Both these softwares allow you to load road data shapefiles, and you can query (select) which roads you want to display and customize the look of it to your liking.

If you want a quick approach (without having to download softwares), I believe ArcGIS has an online portal which allows you to display information you want on top of their base maps. You will still need the shapefile for your streets though. Check this link out, make yourself an account and experiment around with it http://www.arcgis.com/home/. If you click on the Map tab, it takes you to a screen which should allow you to upload shapefiles.

Comment: How would I make a shapefile?

Comment: refer to @eric's answer for obtaining shapefiles, I'm also going to edit the tags in your question to include ArcGIS - there may be some experts out there that would have a better answer

Answer (score 4):

Building upon Suvi's nice answer.

There is a very useful open-source project that collects street data for the entire globe. It's called [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/). On their website you can extract the specific street data you need. It only takes a few clicks and bam! you got the map you need. Their data can also be accessed (perphaps easier for some) from [here](http://downloads.cloudmade.com/) and [here](http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/europe/). Those links can provide you with the shapefile(map) that you need. Your newly aquired map can then be loaded in the free [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) software that was mentioned. There you can easily select the streets you are interested in.

Comment: Ah yes thank you, I was looking for a free and easy to download source for street network datasets - OpenStreetMap did not cross my mind. But this would definitely be the right place to look at, as the answer states you can load this layer onto QuantumGIS and query the streets you need - or I think you may be able to do it in ArcGIS online (the link I provided you).

Comment: Thank you. It's too late now anyway: the presentation was this morning (and I failed horribly), but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You said you were ' going to just draw a map'. If all you need is  a very clean map, you can consider using [iMap Builder](http://www.imapbuilder.net) which is a mapping software supports both map shape files, and custom Google maps. I have used to create some simple map projects before and worked great for me.  You can use their pre-made map templates which shows just the map outlines without any details, you can then add routes / points / mouse-over speech bubbles etc as you need.